# How to fix my issue on python class error?

Tags: python, class, browser

I creating a new browser in python by using pycharm while creating a browser I got bug like.
Saying

```
  class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

What to do? Guide me

Comment: It may not be in here. It may be due to a missing ```)``` or anything in the line above

Comment: Please share the full code and some more code.

Comment: Hi @Sujay
thanks for connecting. They are fine but still
Process finished  with exit code 1

Comment: import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
  (MainWindow, self).__init__()
  self.browser = QWebEngineView()
  self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://google.com'))
  self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
  self.showMaximized()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setapplicationName('Rugusat Browser')
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to include the code with the problem to it. Be sure to preserve the indentations because incorrect indents are one of the possible sources of `SyntaxError`.